# Adicionar espaço extra entre pontilhados com text-decoration-style: dotted;

Tags: html, css

Há alguma forma de adicionar espaço extra entre os pontilhados inseridos com `text-decoration-style: dotted`?

Possuo essa âncora:

```css
.anchor {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-underline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor" href="">
  Hi! Click me
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ainda não existe essa propriedade de dashOffset nativamente no estilo de text-decoration do CSS. Com SVG vc consegue controlar isso. Mas nessa resposta vou passar um workaround com CSS puro usando um `radial-gradiente` no *pseudo-elemento*. Os detalhes deixei comentado no CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da img acima

**Edit**: Fiz um `pseudo-elemento before` para poder deixar toda a área do link clicavel, mesmo o espaço entre o texto e a linha pontilhada. Coloquei uma cor de BG apenas para facilitar a visualização da área do link

```css
.anchor {
  /* text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-underline-offset: 5px; */
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.anchor::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    /* altura entre a linha e o texto */
    bottom: -16px;
    left: 0;
    /* aqui vc controla o tamanho do Dot, no caso ele está com 2px */
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 2px, transparent 2px);
    /* o valor de 16px é a distancia entre um ponto e outro */
    background-size: 16px 4px;
}

.anchor::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    /* o valor de 16px é pq ele deve ser igual ao valor do bottom do ::after */
    height: calc(100% + 16px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #dedede;
    z-index: -1;
}

.anchor:hover::after {
    /* exemplo trocando a cor e o espaçamento no hover */
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red 2px, transparent 2px);
    background-size: 8px 4px;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor" href="">
  Hi! Click me
</a>
```

Comment: boa solução, @hugocsl. Só um ponto, dessa forma, o espaço entre o pontilhado e o texto não é clicável, você sabe alguma alternativa pra suprir isso? esse problema fica evidente quando o espaço horizontal entre os pontilhados e o texto é grande.

Comment: @veroneseComS tem como sim meu caro, deixei o comentário no **edit** e no CSS